# How can a checkbox color be customized without losing checkmark in qml?

Tags: qt, qml

How can a checkbox color of the indicator be customized without changing the checkmark it shows by default?

I'm going to illustrate what happens by default:

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 300
    CheckBox {

    }

}
```

[image]

If i go to documentation the examples I see there don't mantain the checkmark…

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html

Because of that, instead of a Rectangle i use a Text component on the indicator property

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 300
    CheckBox {
        id: control
        indicator: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 26
            implicitHeight: 26
            x: control.leftPadding
            y: parent.height / 2 - height / 2
            radius: 3
            border.color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"

            Text {
                width: 14
                height: 14
                x: 1
                y: -2
                text: "✔"
                font.pointSize: 18
                color: control.down ? "#17a81a" : "#21be2b"
                visible: control.checked
            }
        }
    }

}
```

It doesn't look exactly like the default:

[image]

Is there anything we can do to make it like the default one?

Answer (score 2):

A brute force solution is to copy the implementation of the `CheckBox.qml` to your own code and then to change the required parts. It turned out that the check symbol is not a text, but moreover a simple image.

The following would give you a CheckBox being the same as `CheckBox.qml`, but having a green Check-Symbol instead of a black work. I copied this code from Qt 5.13.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Templates 2.12 as T
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls.impl 2.12

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    title: "Stack"
    visible: true
    width: 300
    CheckBox {
        id: control
        indicator: Rectangle {
        implicitWidth: 28
        implicitHeight: 28

        x: control.mirrored ? control.leftPadding : control.width - width - control.rightPadding
        y: control.topPadding + (control.availableHeight - height) / 2

        color: control.down ? control.palette.light : control.palette.base
        border.width: control.visualFocus ? 2 : 1
        border.color: control.visualFocus ? control.palette.highlight : control.palette.mid

        ColorImage {
            x: (parent.width - width) / 2
            y: (parent.height - height) / 2
            defaultColor: "#353637"
            color: "green" // Added this
            source: "qrc:/qt-project.org/imports/QtQuick/Controls.2/images/check.png"
            visible: control.checkState === Qt.Checked
        }
        Rectangle {
            x: (parent.width - width) / 2
            y: (parent.height - height) / 2
            width: 16
            height: 3
            color: control.palette.text
            visible: control.checkState === Qt.PartiallyChecked
        }
    }
    }

}
```

I guess, that there is no way to override parts of the ColorImage component, as there is no `id` being set, so that the color property cannot be redefined.

Comment: This seems like the solution i was looking, nice. Btw what is the easeast way to look at the implementation of the controls? there is not way to ctrl+click on imports

Comment: @Ngranja1512: I did it the hard way. Searching the sources for CheckBox.qml. You can do so on GitHub. Actually, I don't consider my solution as a good one. Just imagine what might happen, if you have to change your Qt version. The solution might be broken.

Comment: yes youre right, and i think it will happen in the future in my case. Another problem is that the color of the image is not configurable. But i'll expose that to my boss.

Comment: This is exactly what the Qt Documentation recommends as one of the approaches. See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a somewhat hackish solution, that could break if CheckBox implementation details change:

```
CheckBox
{

     font.italic: !hasReferential
     font.pointSize: 8
     indicator.width: 15
     indicator.height: 15
     Component.onCompleted: indicator.children[0].color = "green"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the way that gives you the most control over customizing a checkbox (or most other controls for that matter) can be found on the [Customizing Qt Quick Controls](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-checkbox) page.

If all you want to do is change the color of the checkmark, I've found that with Qt/QML version (5.12.2) some of the checkbox colors can be customized using the `palette` property of the checkbox.  Like so:

```
Checkbox
{
   text:"checkered past"
   checked: true
   palette{
      base: "white"       // color of check background
      mid: "black"        // color of border around check background
      text: "green"       // color of the checkmark
      windowText: "black" // color of the label text (in this case "checkered past")
   }
}
```